# Add single quotes and comma from input from textarea using php

Tags: php, html

I have input from a textarea using php i need to figure out how to do the following

input

```
number1
number2
number3
number4
```

need to have output like

```
'number1',
'number2',
'number3',
'number4'
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Split the input at newlines, put quotes around each element of the array, then join them with comma-newline.

Comment: This does rather fail the basic *"what have you tried and where are you stuck"* acid test...

Comment: And somehow it got an upvote.

Comment: sorry i should of posted what I had
<pre>
$numbers = $_POST['accountnumbers'];

$numbersarray = array($numbers);

$numbersoutput  =  "'".join("', '", $numbersarray)."'";

echo '<font color="white">'.$numbersoutput.'</font>';
</pre>

Comment: please use the [edit] link to add required information to your original question. Not only does it get buried in a comment - code is almost impossible to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `join` function:

```
$input = "number1
number2
number3
number4";

$lines = explode("|", preg_replace( "/([\r\n])+/", "|", $input));

$output = "'".join("',\n'", $lines)."'";

echo $output;
```

Output:

```
'number1',
'number2',
'number3',
'number4'
```

**Explaination**:

The line `preg_replace( "/([\r\n])+/", "|", $input)` is needed to match any different type of line terminating and carriage return.

`explode` is used to split the string into smallest pieces by the `|`

`join` is used to concat the lines into a single string as you desire.

Try it [here](https://eval.in/942739).

Comment: I tried that and I get  ''

Comment: This requires `$input` to be an array.

Comment: I'm rewriting it.

Comment: Answer edited .